# How to open a xls file that seems to have something wrong in R

Tags: r, xls

I have a xls file that I cannot open in R. I've tried a lot and the best I got was something like:

```
data = read.table('D:/Usuario/pivo1/table.xls', sep = ';')
```

but the df comes in this form:

[image]

while it should be something like this:

[image]

Aditionally:

> print(data[9,1])

[image]

We can see the numbers of interest. Dates, hours and etc. but this form, in line 9 and column 1 of the df.

None of the excel functions worked, this was the best result i got.

I have a dropbox link for the file access:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/jlo15oasidxrbvvbcl3ge/table.xls?rlkey=ny8804ox4yqb1nqs9wn33j5ak&dl=0

Thanks for the help, i still have no solution. Working manually on the data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's difficult to answer without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) - is it possible to provide a link to the xls file? Your data contains HTML and we don't know how that got there.

Comment: Is this an Excel file? `read.table()` is for plain text files, like comma-separated or tab-separated values. You could try a package for reading Excel files, such as the `read_xls()` or `read_xlsx()` functions from the `readxl` package.

Comment: Yes, I completely failed to notice the key issue :) `read.table` is not for xls files.

Comment: I've tried many functions from Tydiverse, Readxl, openxlsx packages and none of them worked. The only "result" i got was this weird df using the read.table( ), where my data is all inside one of the cells, and unsuitable for use. Unfortunately, I can't post my excel file here, this is not in conform with StackOverflow policy.

Comment: @MatheusWestphalen Could you please add the code how you have tried to read the Excel sheet besides `read.table`? Then we may will be able to figure out the solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late update. I have a dropbox link for the file access: 

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/jlo15oasidxrbvvbcl3ge/table.xls?rlkey=ny8804ox4yqb1nqs9wn33j5ak&dl=0 

Thanks for the help, i still have no solution. Working manually on the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file contains HTML for a table and is somehow saved with *xls* extension:

```html
<table id="tb1">            
            <tbody><tr>
                <th>DATA</th>
                <th>HORA</th>
                <th>VOLUME (m³)</th>
                <th>HORIMETRO</th>
            </tr>
            
        <tr>...</tr></tbody></table>
```

Somewhat surprisingly Excel can actually handle this, even though it does complain about format and extension mismatch.

You can open the file and parse the table with `{rvest}`:

```r
library(rvest)
read_html("table.xls") |>
  html_element("table") |>
  html_table()
#> # A tibble: 162 × 4
#>    DATA     HORA  `VOLUME (m³)` HORIMETRO
#>    <chr>    <chr> <chr>             <dbl>
#>  1 23/04/23 00:00 0253037 m³         514.
#>  2 23/04/23 01:00 0253037 m³         514.
#>  3 23/04/23 02:00 0253037 m³         514.
#>  4 23/04/23 03:00 0253037 m³         514.
#>  5 23/04/23 04:00 0253037 m³         514.
#>  6 23/04/23 05:00 0253037 m³         514.
#>  7 23/04/23 06:00 0253037 m³         514.
#>  8 23/04/23 07:00 0253037 m³         514.
#>  9 23/04/23 08:00 0253037 m³         514.
#> 10 23/04/23 09:00 0253037 m³         514.
#> # ℹ 152 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To read Excel files (actually worksheets or part(s) of worksheets from Excel files) in `R` you have several options. e.g.:

- `read_excel` function from [`readxl` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/readme/README.html) (part of [`tidyverse`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyverse/readme/README.html))
- `read.xlsx` or `read.xlsx2` functions from [`xlsx` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/readme/README.html)
- `read.xlsx` function from [`openxlsx` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/readme/README.html)
- `readWorksheetFromFile` function (and several other) from [`XLConnect` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/readme/README.html)